# When Kxmovie plays .rm format file, the audio does not work fine

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, rm

I used third party video player KxMovie to play video in my app, the video streams fluently but the audio keeps on-and-off in a regular way, how to solve it? What's the possible reason for this problem?

Parameters about the .rm format video:

[image: parameters about the .rm format video]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace code in method `- (KxAudioFrame *) handleAudioFrame` with code below:
Original Code:

```
numFrames = swr_convert(_swrContext,
                    outbuf,
                    numFrames * 2,
                    (const uint8_t **)_audioFrame->data,
                    numFrames);
```

New Code:

```
numFrames = swr_convert(_swrContext,
                    outbuf,
                    _audioFrame->nb_samples * 2,
                    (const uint8_t **)_audioFrame->data,
                    _audioFrame->nb_samples);
```

See what you can get.